# action.setCallback in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

```
getAllvehicleList : function(component, event, helper)
{
    var action = component.get("c.retrieveVehicle");
    action.setParams({'status':component.get("v.status")});
    action.setCallback(this, fuction(data) {
                                            

enter code here

component.set('v.vehicleList',data.getRetrunValue())                       
                                            });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Line  : 5
Error : Parsing error: Unexpected token {

Please explain the error which come at line number 4 in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled the JavaScript keyword `function` incorrectly.

You have also misspelled the standard Aura method name `getReturnValue()`.

Making errors like this will often cause the compiler to show you errors that do not obviously make sense because they do not reflect your *intent*, but rather what you actually wrote. You'll be able to make progress more quickly if you develop the skill of proofreading your own code. Syntax highlighting in your editor and tools like ESLint can also help spot this type of mistake.